# Delay an animation – Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using the following code to animate a circle. However, it is constantly blinking. I want to delay the restart of the animation by  5 seconds. How can I do that?

```
-(void)start
{    
    [self removeExistingAnimation];
    
    //create the image
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redCircle.png"];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    [self addSubview:imageView];
    
    //opacity animation setup
    CABasicAnimation *opacityAnimation;
    
    opacityAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    opacityAnimation.duration = ANIMATION_DURATION;
    opacityAnimation.repeatCount = ANIMATION_REPEAT;
    //theAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
    opacityAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.6];
    opacityAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.025];
    //resize animation setup
    CABasicAnimation *transformAnimation;
    
    transformAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    
    transformAnimation.duration = ANIMATION_DURATION;
    transformAnimation.repeatCount = ANIMATION_REPEAT;
    //transformAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
    transformAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:MIN_RATIO];
    transformAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:MAX_RATIO];
    
    //group the two animation
    CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    
    group.repeatCount = ANIMATION_REPEAT;
    [group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:opacityAnimation, transformAnimation, nil]];
    group.duration = ANIMATION_DURATION;

    //apply the grouped animaton
    [imageView.layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"groupAnimation"];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this :

```
-(void)start
{    
    [self removeExistingAnimation];

    //create the image
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redCircle.png"];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    [self addSubview:imageView];

    [self doAnimation];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(doAnimation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)doAnimation
{

//opacity animation setup
    CABasicAnimation *opacityAnimation;

    opacityAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    opacityAnimation.duration = ANIMATION_DURATION;
    opacityAnimation.repeatCount = ANIMATION_REPEAT;
    //theAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
    opacityAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.6];
    opacityAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.025];
    //resize animation setup
    CABasicAnimation *transformAnimation;

    transformAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];

    transformAnimation.duration = ANIMATION_DURATION;
    transformAnimation.repeatCount = ANIMATION_REPEAT;
    //transformAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
    transformAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:MIN_RATIO];
    transformAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:MAX_RATIO];

    //group the two animation
    CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];

    group.repeatCount = ANIMATION_REPEAT;
    [group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:opacityAnimation, transformAnimation, nil]];
    group.duration = ANIMATION_DURATION;

    //apply the grouped animaton
    [imageView.layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"groupAnimation"];

}
```

This is look like dirty method but worked for me , hop it help you..

Comment: @MuhammadUmar which framework are you using for this animation?

Comment: QuartzCore. It works if i remove opacityAnimation.duration = ANIMATION_DURATION; and other animation durations but there is still one bug when animation stops, the imageView is still added in the self and i can see big Red Circle. I want to remove this circle something like atEndAnimation call function removeExistingAnimation

Comment: yes,you are right its working fine if you remove all duration code.

Comment: But you are making it constantly blinking, do you want to make it end after some blink? in my code i see it perfectly blinking.

Comment: what is the value of min and max ratio?

Comment: it is blinking alright but with this code it never stops for 5 seconds.I want to put a delay in each blink.once it blinks then it waits for 5 seconds to start. Actually it is not blinking , it is moving outward like a wave. Once the wave completes it should wait for 5 seconds for next wave to come

Comment: If you want to make it just blink and not waving then, delete code of transformAnimation ,and our code is making it delay for 5 second .

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a bit cleaner? Or is there a reason why you can't use blocks for animating?

```
    - (void) start {
        //create the image
        UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redCircle.png"];
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
        [self addSubview:imageView];

        [self animateWithDelay:0.0];
    }

    - (void) animateWithDelay:(CGFloat)delay {

        imageView.alpha = 0.0;
        imageView.transfrom = CGAffineTransformScale(myImage.transform, MIN_RATIO, MIN_RATIO);
        [UIImageView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION delay:delay options:0 animations:^{

            imageView.alpha = 1.0;
            imageView.transfrom = CGAffineTransformScale(myImage.transform, MAX_RATIO, MAX_RATIO);

        } completion:^{
            animationCount++;
            if (ANIMATION_REPEAT != animationCount) {
                [self animateWithDelay:5.0];
            }
        }]; 

    }
```

You should define animationCount somewhere in your class, so you know when he should stop repeating.

(Not tested, so could contain some errors)